# Как получить информацию о том, какую роль в дискорде занимает человек discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Как в коде python с помощью библиотеки discord.py получить сведения о том, какую роль занимает человек?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужен список ролей (на сервере) участника. Представим ситуацию, что пользователю нужно по команде `myroles` получить список ролей:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['myroles']) 
async def _myroles(ctx):
      member = ctx.message.author 
      member_roles = member.roles 
      await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} список твоих ролей:\n{member_roles}")
```